How to use additional_inputs and examples at the same time?
In Gradio, I tried chatinterface with "additional_inputs" and "examples" at the same time.
But, only either of them can work.
How do I use those two features at the same time?
When "examples" is commented out, then, "additional_inputs" can work.
When "additional_inputs" is commented out, "examples" can work.
Here is the example I tried:
import gradio as gr

def yes_man(message, history, input1):
    return f"{input1}" 
  
with gr.Blocks() as demo:
      input1 = gr.Textbox("", label="input1")
     
      gr.ChatInterface(
          yes_man, 
          examples=["Hello", "Am I cool?", "Are tomatoes vegetables?"],
          additional_inputs=[input1],
      )
        
demo.launch()


In this case, if input1 has "good", the return should be "good" in the chatbot.
Actually, not only "examples" but also other functions canot work, if "additional_inputs is used.
textbox=gr.Textbox(placeholder="Ask me a yes or no question", container=False, scale=7),


Normally you have only one input - for message - so every example needs only one value.
When you use additional_inputs then you have more inputs
and every example must have more value - so every example has to be a list (it can't be a tuple).
examples=[
  ### [value for textbox, value for input1]  # it can't be tuple
  ["Hello", ""], 
  ["Am I cool?", ""],
  ["Are tomatoes vegetables?", ""]
],

Documentation: Example Inputs

Full working example with 2 additional inputs - so every example must have 3 values.
import gradio as gr

print('gradio:', gr.__version__)

def yes_man(message, history, input_1, input_2):
    print('message:', message)
    print('history:', history)
    print('input_1:', input_1)
    print('input_2:', input_2)
    
    return f"{message} (I've been {input_1} for {input_2} days)" 
  
with gr.Blocks() as demo:     
      gr.ChatInterface(
          yes_man, 
          examples=[
            ### [Example Inputs](https://www.gradio.app/guides/the-interface-class#example-inputs)
            ### [value for textbox, value for input_1, value for input_2]  # it can't be tuple
            ["Hello",                    "nice", "123"],
            ["Am I cool?",               "fun",  "456"], 
            ["Are tomatoes vegetables?", "sad",  "789"],
            #["Say something",           "",     ""],  # empty values 
          ],
          additional_inputs=[
            #gr.Dropdown(["", "nice", "fun", "sad", "angry"], label="Mood"), #, allow_custom_value=True),
            gr.Textbox("", label="Mood"),
            gr.Textbox("", label="Days")
          ],
      )
        
demo.launch()



If you set None for some input in all examples then it will not display this column in example
and example will not change current value in for this input.
Documentation: Providing Partial Examples
  examples=[
    ### [value for textbox, value for input_1, value for input_2]  # it can't be tuple
    ### [Providing Partial Examples](https://www.gradio.app/guides/more-on-examples#providing-partial-examples)
    # if column has only `None` then it doesn't display this input  # this will skip `Mood`
    ["Hello",                    None, "123"],       
    ["Am I cool?",               None, "456"],
    ["Are tomatoes vegetables?", None, "789"],
    ["Say something",            None, ""],
  ],


